# How to prevent v-tabs component to render vertical scrollbar across almost empty page?

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

Given a very small Vue app with a single Vuetify tabs component that will be embedded inside an iframe

( [Reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpNjEsKgCAUAK8ib125Dws6R7Ywkwj8PPQpSHT3pFWbWQzMrDekqPmCOJRsYARBxqFVZGbpGROlJ7Untp+9DjbESQLGy6lYJbDD+HRRbU4Hh0pTc7xlgv8e8HQ+W/thewFAUSaY) )

```
<template>
  <v-tabs bg-color="primary" />
</template>
```

When running the small app it will render a vertical scroll bar but there is enough space on the page. How can I fix this behaviour?

---

*Seems this happens in Chrome but not in Firefox*

Answer (score -2):

If the Vue app with the Vuetify tabs component is rendering a vertical scroll bar even though there is enough space on the page, it could be due to the default styles of Vuetify or CSS conflicts within the iframe. Here are a few approaches you can try to fix this behavior:

Custom Styling: Apply custom CSS to override any default styles that may be causing the vertical scrollbar to appear unnecessarily. You can target the specific elements causing the issue and adjust their styles accordingly.

Adjust Container Size: Ensure that the container of the Vue app within the iframe has enough height to accommodate the content without needing a scrollbar. You can adjust the height of the iframe or the container element within the parent document.

Vuetify Configuration: Check if there are any configuration options provided by Vuetify that allow you to control the behavior of the tabs component, such as adjusting padding, margins, or other layout-related properties.

Inspect Styles: Use browser developer tools to inspect the styles applied to the elements within the iframe. Identify any conflicting styles or properties that might be causing the scrollbar to appear unexpectedly.

Use overflow: hidden: If you're sure that there's enough space and the scrollbar is appearing due to some overflow, you can try applying overflow: hidden to the container element within the iframe to prevent the scrollbar from appearing.

Here's an example of how you can apply custom styling to adjust the behavior of the tabs component:

```
<template>
  <v-tabs class="custom-tabs" bg-color="primary" density="compact" />
</template>

<style>
.custom-tabs {
  /* Adjust padding or margins if necessary */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

Make sure to replace .custom-tabs with the appropriate CSS selector targeting the tabs component or its container.

If none of these approaches work, providing more context or code snippets may help in diagnosing the issue more accurately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy